# Spawn ENOENT error when using npx create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npx

I'm getting a strange and rather uninformative error after attempting to create a new react app using 'npx create-react-app'.

```
$ npx create-react-app client
spawn C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin ENOENT
```

For some reason it's pointing to my mongoDB folder, this only started after I installed mongoDB on my laptop for the first time. I have no idea how to replicate this error on another system.

I've tried uninstalling mongoDB as well, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the npm cache .. cache located in appdata folder .

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've tried clearing my npm cache in appdata/roaming, but unfortunately the problem persists.